# I get this Error java in pentaho when I start a job

Tags: java, pentaho

Could anyone please explain this error that I get when a job started. I have a scheduling lunch system for each kjb or ktr  and some are Ok and green and when it arrive at some ktr or kjb it gives me this error that I don't understand :

```
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched - ERROR (version 8.3.0.0-371, build 8.3.0.0-371 from 2019-06-11 11.09.08 by buildguy) : Error running job entry 'job' :
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched - ERROR (version 8.3.0.0-371, build 8.3.0.0-371 from 2019-06-11 11.09.08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched - Unexpected error during job metadata load
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at java.lang.Thread.run (null:-1)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJobRunner.run
> (JobEntryJobRunner.java:69)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:565)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:686)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.execute
> (JobEntryJob.java:695)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta
> (JobEntryJob.java:1373)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta
> (JobEntryJob.java:1409)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMetaFromRepository
> (JobEntryJob.java:1388)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched - 
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta(JobEntryJob.java:1449)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta(JobEntryJob.java:1373)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.execute(JobEntryJob.java:695)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:686)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:827)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:565)`enter code here`
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJobRunner.run(JobEntryJobRunner.java:69)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMetaFromRepository(JobEntryJob.java:1388)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta(JobEntryJob.java:1409)
>     2023/06/01 09:28:35 - job script launched -   ... 11 more
```